# Can I use 'where' inside a for-loop in swift?

Tags: for-loop, swift, where-clause, for-in-loop

Is there also a possibility to use the 'where' keyword in another place then a switch? Can I use it in a for in loop for example?

I have an array with bools, all with a value, can I do something like this:

```
var boolArray: [Bool] = []

//(...) set values and do stuff


for value where value == true in boolArray {
   doSomething()
}
```

This would be a lot nicer than use an if, so I am wondering if there is a possibility to use where in combination with a for-loop. Ty for your time.

Comment: `for value in boolArray.filter(){ $0 == true }` like that?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Wow yeah thanks, thats very nice and swifty!

Comment: Glad I could help - just wanted to be clear that's what you want - adding an answer

Comment: Note that using both `filter` and a `for` loop means the array has to be traversed more than once (first to filter, then again on the filtered array). An `if` inside a `for` might not look spiffy, but it'll almost always be more efficient.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In Swift 2, new `where` syntax was added:

```
for value in boolArray where value == true {
   ...
}
```

In Pre 2.0 one solution would be to call `.filter` on the array before you iterate it:

```
for value in boolArray.filter({ $0 == true }) {
   doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Good solution. For style, though, I'd suggest *not* using trailing closure syntax — that way it's clearer which set of braces is the body of the `for` loop: `for value in boolArray.filter({ $0 == true }) { doSomething() }`

Comment: Ben, can you tell me why the for loop below doesn't get executed? Also view isn't recognized as UIBarButtonItem automatically. 

        for view in self.view.subviews where view.isKindOfClass(UIBarButtonItem) {
            view.enabled = false
        }

Answer (score 10):

A normal `for-loop` will iterate all elements present in the list. But sometimes we want to iterate only when data satisfy some condition, there we can use `where` clause with `for -loop`. It's just a replacement of `if` condition inside the loop.

For example:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for data in numbers {
    if (data % 2 == 0) {
        print(data)
    }
}
```

can be rewritten in the simpler way as:

```
for data in numbers where data % 2 == 0 {
    print(data)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can use **"where"** clause with for loop.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for value in arr where value != 0 {
    print(value)
}
```

Considering your example,

```
var boolArray: [Bool] = []

//(...) set values and do stuff

for value in boolArray where value == true {
   doSomething()
}
```